# GCLOUD IAM VPN into gcp network

Tags: vpn, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

We want to create a VPN into our GCP network where users are authorized using their IAM credentials. This way we can hide our development servers from the outside world but not from the office/for our developers. We are aware of IAP but we would prefer using a VPN.

Thanks in advance,
kvanzuijlen

Answer (score 1):

the VPN just creates a tunnel from your network to the Google VPC network. There is no IAM integration with this.

Using the Cloud VPN, your onsite network will have direct access to your servers where as the outside world will not. The outside world will not use the VPN connection.

IAP is the best method to expose your servers to the outside world while requiring credentials to access the resource.